# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No AWS profile named '_________' how to fix that?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No AWS profile named 'danekerscode'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPXdk.png)
why I got this error?
i wanna implement email sending through amazon  web services, but i got this errors

Comment: Where do you get this error? Do you have a Java application using AWS SDK?

Comment: Did you add your access_key and secret_key to your credential profile?

Answer (score 0):

To send email by using AWS and the Java programming language, use the ***AWS SDK for Java v2***. You need to setup your AWS credentials that is explained here in the Java V2 DEV Guide:

[Default credentials provider chain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/credentials-chain.html)

Once you have your credentials setup, using a Java IDE, create a project and then add a POM to your Java project. You can find a POM that works here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/ses/pom.xml

Now you can write Java app logic to send email messages. The following Java code example uses the SES Java API to send a message:

```
// snippet-start:[ses.java2.sendmessage.request.import]
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ses.SesClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ses.model.Content;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ses.model.Destination;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ses.model.Message;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ses.model.Body;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ses.model.SendEmailRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ses.model.SesException;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;
// snippet-end:[ses.java2.sendmessage.request.import]

/**
 * Before running this Java V2 code example, set up your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For more information, see the following documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */
public class SendMessageEmailRequest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String usage = "\n" +
            "Usage:\n" +
            "    <sender> <recipient> <subject> \n\n" +
            "Where:\n" +
            "    sender - An email address that represents the sender. \n"+
            "    recipient -  An email address that represents the recipient. \n"+
            "    subject - The  subject line. \n" ;

        if (args.length != 3) {
            System.out.println(usage);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String sender = args[0];
        String recipient = args[1];
        String subject = args[2];

        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        SesClient client = SesClient.builder()
            .region(region)
            .credentialsProvider(ProfileCredentialsProvider.create())
            .build();

        // The HTML body of the email.
        String bodyHTML = "<html>" + "<head></head>" + "<body>" + "<h1>Hello!</h1>"
                + "<p> See the list of customers.</p>" + "</body>" + "</html>";

        try {
            send(client, sender, recipient, subject, bodyHTML);
            client.close();
            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // snippet-start:[ses.java2.sendmessage.request.main]
    public static void send(SesClient client,
                            String sender,
                            String recipient,
                            String subject,
                            String bodyHTML
    ) throws MessagingException {

        Destination destination = Destination.builder()
            .toAddresses(recipient)
            .build();

        Content content = Content.builder()
            .data(bodyHTML)
            .build();

        Content sub = Content.builder()
            .data(subject)
            .build();

        Body body = Body.builder()
            .html(content)
            .build();

        Message msg = Message.builder()
            .subject(sub)
            .body(body)
            .build();

        SendEmailRequest emailRequest = SendEmailRequest.builder()
            .destination(destination)
            .message(msg)
            .source(sender)
            .build();

        try {
            System.out.println("Attempting to send an email through Amazon SES " + "using the AWS SDK for Java...");
            client.sendEmail(emailRequest);

        } catch (SesException e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    // snippet-end:[ses.java2.sendmessage.request.main]
}
```

You can find this example and many others in the AWS Code Lib:

[Amazon SES examples using SDK for Java 2.x](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/java_2_ses_code_examples.html)